# SQL Server BACKUP 'stop_on_error' option

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-backups

When using **stop_on_error** option in SQL Server, what actually happens if you overwrite existing `*.bak` file?

Would it stop before overwriting the existing valid backup or mess up the correct existing backup and then stop the operation?

The official documentation does not explain this in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talking from experience, few weeks ago I was overriding an existing backup file (there was no available space) and the backup failed on 99% (!). Sql2008.
The size of the original bak file didn't change, but when i tried to restore it - it gave an error that the "header of the backup was corrupted" and restore failed.
Not sure, if this happens always, but from now on - i backup to a different file and switch after validation of the backup is successful.